# According to Islam, why was I born?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, creation

Why was I born, according to Islam?

In fact, I also have a second component to this question. If Allah/God is omniscient, then why did he create beings that he knew were certain to enter hell (which he also created)?

Even assuming he gave us 'free will', he **knew** when he created us who would end up 'choosing' hell. So why would he create them? Is this not injustice? I kindly ask for answers in light of the Quran and Sunnah, as to distinguish this question from merely delving into philosophy.

Comment: S.a. Every soul on this planet came voluntary. We have all agreed to this test here on earth. The mountains, however, have refused. So you "knew" what you were getting into at the beginning, or you thought you knew and were convinced you could do it. So obey Allah and inshallah go to paradise.

Answer (score 1):

You inquired a very significant question which in all probability is the question of many people. So this is a very important question which need a detailed answer as a helpful answer (to persuade the questioners).

But here I strive to mention it quite briefly in some sentences.

**Allah in the Holy Quran mentioned that:**

> I created you just for Ibadah(Worshipping).
>
> «وَمَا خَلَقْتُ الْجِنَّ وَالْإِنسَ إِلَّا لِیَعْبُدُونِ») الذاریات،
> 56)

**We can survey it from the aspect of worship as it mentioned according to the verse above.**

**On the other hand, this is correct that Allah doesn’t require our worshiping, but in truth it (creating of humans) could be a way to convey them to the perfection (الکمال). Actually we can say that reaching the perfection is considered as a main reason for the creation of the humans.**

---

Source:

- [tebyan.net](https://article.tebyan.net/229733/)

Comment: -1. I don't see how this answers question. *"why did he create beings that he knew were certain to enter hell"*

Answer (score 1):

Allah/God created humans giving us 'free will' for the following reasons.

> - Who has created death and life, that he may test you which of you is best in deed. And he is the Almighty, Oft Forgiving. (Qur'an 67:2).
> - And We have enjoined on man (to be dutiful and good) to his parents. His mother bore him in weakness and hardship upon weakness and hardship, and his weaning is in two years give thanks to Me and to your parents, unto Me is the final destination. (Qur'an 31:14)
> - And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. I do not want from them any provision, nor do I want them to feed Me. (Qur'an 51:56-57)

By observing the above 3 verses, God wants us to have a balance of the above.

> He it is Who sends Salat (His blessings) on you, and His angels too (ask Allah to bless and forgive you), that He may bring you out from darkness (of disbelief and polytheism) into light (of Belief and Islamic Monotheism). And He is Ever Most Merciful to the believers. (Quran 33:43)

People burn in hell only because of their deeds. While they're born, God doesn't stamp them that they're to be in hell for sure or pre decide, but tests. So there is no injustice done to them. So, in this God is justifying to us that those who burn in hell deserved it.

But, assuming he had knowledge of future, when he was certain about that, then, He creates as he wishes.

> Blessed is He in Whose Hand is the dominion, and He is Able to do all things. (Qur'an 67:1)

May the creator guide us all.