# According to Islam, is God (Allah) omniscient?

Tags: quran, allah, islamic-philosophy

> omniscient
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> **Knowing everything** - (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/omniscient)

Do the **core teachings** of Islam, (e.g. those found in the Quran), say that God (Allah) is omniscient?

To clarify, I am looking for evidence of Allah's omniscience from Islam's core teachings.

---

This is somewhat *related* to another question of mine, although the two can not be *equated*: [According to Islam, why was I born?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18345/according-to-islam-why-was-i-born)

Answer (score 3):

Yes...

That's what the **Qur'an** says.

> إِن تُبْدُوا شَيْئًا أَوْ تُخْفُوهُ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ كَانَ بِكُلِّ
>   شَيْءٍ عَلِيمًا
>
> İn tubdû şey’en ev tuhfûhu fe innallâhe kâne bi kulli şey’in alîmâ.

*Surat Al-'Aĥzāb 33/54*

Meaning:

> Whether you divulge a thing or keep it hidden, surely Allah is Ever
>   All-Knowing of all things